# Angular 8 - Process Route subscription when navigates to same route path

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing, angular-router

I am receiving route notifications from a back-end application, to load Angular components. Example:

```
// Current route "/example1/path1"
let route = "/example2/path1"; //route received from back-end
this.router.navigate([route]); // OK: navigates to component associated to "/example2/path1" path
```

Also, in each component I am processing route notifications inside a subscription:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
...
            }
        });
```

Nevertheless, I am having some troubles to navigate to the same component on some received routes, let's say:

```
// Current route "/example1/path1"
let route = "/example1/path1"; //route received from back-end (SAME ROUTE PATH)
this.router.navigate([route]); // NOK: route notification not received in subscription
```

My question is: Are there any way to receive this notification on subscription when application needs to navigate to the same route? Query params would be a valid solution for me ex.: "/example1/path1?timestamp=1234567", nevertheless I don't know how could I parse "timestamp" and "path1" separately without creating a separate parse method...

I would appreciate any kind of help or suggestion about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this solution has been valid for this purpose:

```
private navigateURL(route: string /* URL received from BackEnd*/) {
    let urlTree: UrlTree = this.router.parseUrl(route);
    const fragmentUrl = urlTree.fragment;
    const queryParams = urlTree.queryParams;
    urlTree.fragment = null;
    urlTree.queryParams = {};
    const url = this.router.serializeUrl(urlTree);
    this.router.navigate([url], {queryParams: queryParams, fragment: fragmentUrl });
}
```

To subscribe on Query String params using `ActivatedRoute`:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(data => {
})
```

To subscribe on Fragment:

```
this.route.fragment.subscribe(data => {
})
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information

```
this.router.navigate(["/example1/path1"],{timestamp: 1234567});
```

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {} 

ngOnInit() {
 // "/example1/path1?timestamp=1234567"
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.timestamp = params['timestamp'];
  });
}
```

Comment: it does not receive notification after this.router.navigate(["/example1/path1?timestamp=1234567"]);

Comment: try that ```this.router.navigate(["/example1/path1"],{timestamp: 1234567});``` more info in https://angular.io/guide/router#specifying-a-relative-route  @AlbertoBricio

Comment: Sorry but, after execute this.router.navigate(["/example1/path1"],{timestamp: 1234567});, with diferent timestamp values when user is in the same route path,  this.route.queryParams subscription is not notified

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
  window.location.href = path
```

But in general you should avoid "reload all the applicacion". That's, use an auxiliar function and call in subscription or whatever

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.initialize(params)
})

initialize(param){
  ..what ever..
}
```

Then,

```
let route = "/example1/path1"; //route received from back-end (SAME ROUTE PATH)
if (route==this.router.url)
  this.initialize("path1")
else
   this.router.navigate([route]);
```

Comment: how could I initialize a component from beginning in initialize(route){}? Are there any way to reload a component without this.router.navigate?

Comment: what do you want to do when you "reload a component"?  If it's only show new data, only you need refresh de data in .ts. Really I don't think you want to ngDestroy and ngCreate again the component